# Creating a maven project from existing sources. Best way to create the dependency entries from the jars in project library

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Want to shift to maven for my old java web project. So created a basic pom.xml using IntelliJ Idea facility. The project is a J2EE web project and also uses axis 2 1.7.7 . All the jars are in 'lib' directory inside the project structure. Is there a easy way to find out the dependency entries which will be required in the newly created 'pom.xml' . What I mean is a a tool which can pickup the jars one by one and suggest the dependency entries

Any help will be highly appreciated here.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a tool.

Note that you probably only need to add some of the dependencies because Maven resolves transitive dependencies automatically.

So I would look into the source code, figure out which classes you import and add the appropriate dependencies.